# Order of subgroups formed by elements whose order divides a prime power

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a CP-group and $|G|={p_1}^{n_1}…{p_k}^{n_k}$ that $p_i$'s are distinct primes and $n_i>0$.
Also $V_i=\{g\in {G};o(g)|{p_i}^{n_i}\}$, $1≤i≤k$.

1. What is $|V_i|$?
2. There are $V_i $ and $V_j$ that $| V_i |=| V_j |,i≠j$.

Comment: What is a CP-group?

Comment: A group is called a CP-group if every element of the group
has prime power order.